# Linq using how to use order by and group by with left join?

Tags: linq

I have written this query in linq using left join and using group by and order by. I have 2 tables, student and course. So i am grouping on student table after I am not getting any columns in course so how can I order by on course table in datetime column.

tablestudent :

id,name,std

tablecourse :

id,userid,datetime

This is my query :

```
 var res = (from u in db.student
              join c in db.course on u.id equals c.userid into j1
              from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()                       
              group j2 by u.id into g
              orderby g.Key.datatime descending    // here i'm getting datetime does not contain.
              select new { id = g.key }).tolist(); // here i just want id not getting any other column.
```

If anyone knows how to do that, please help.

Comment: Can you show student and course entities and what columns you want to select

Comment: ok i edit my question and show my entities.

Comment: i edited my question.and i want to all entities like name,std adn in course table in datetime with order by

Comment: @jitender have you idea about this query please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one

```
   var query =db.course.GroupBy(c => c.UserId)
             .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.datetime).FirstOrDefault());
        var res = (from u in db.student
              join c in query on u.id equals c.userid into j1
              from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()     
              select new {   u.name,j2}).ToList();
```

[Working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6yLDYJ)

Comment: i have try this wave but i getting in course table all the data i don't want to all data in order by datetime just getting letus first record. sry i am clear saying in question.can you help me this one

Comment: mean just want to firstordefault record in the course table using datetime order by with

Comment: can you please help me how can get first or default using last updated record using datetime with your solution.

Comment: @coderwill do you want to get the list of students with firstordefault datetime from course table order by datetime?

Comment: yes i want like this means ex 1 user in student table then course table suupose userid 1 is 3 entry so i want last entry get using datetime

Comment: hi i am gettting like this error 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.' i am write in select new {lastseen = Helpers.TimeAgo(j2.datetime.Value)}

Comment: i am getting any datetime column in select new {} that time getting error like this i am saying in comment and also onther is null getting datetime like this

Comment: new {lastseen = j2 != null ?Helpers.TimeAgo(j2.datetime.Value) : null}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139642/discussion-between-jitender-and-coderwill).

Comment: hii can you please give me ans on discussion chat?